# Birt null pointer exception

Tags: java, birt

```
        config = new EngineConfig();
        config.setEngineHome( "C:/birt-runtime-3_7_0/ReportEngine" );
        // config.setLogConfig("c:/temp", Level.FINE);

        Platform.startup( config );  //If using RE API in Eclipse/RCP application this is not needed.
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject( IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
        IReportEngine engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );
        // engine.changeLogLevel( Level.WARNING );

        //Open a report design 
        IReportRunnable design = engine.openReportDesign("C:/birt-runtime-3_7_0/ReportEngine/samples/bookingConfirmationBatch.rptdesign"); 

        IGetParameterDefinitionTask task = engine.createGetParameterDefinitionTask( design );
        Collection params = task.getParameterDefns( true );

        //Create task to run and render the report,
        IRunAndRenderTask task2 = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
```

-----i am being scheduled!!------

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.nighttale.scheduling.BookReportGenerator.runBatchReport(BookReportGenerator.java:38)
    at net.nighttale.scheduling.SendBookMail.doPost(SendBookMail.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue but for what i've understand of Birt 3.7,
you don't need to set Birt Home anymore, just copy the jars in ReportEngine/lib
and had them to your classpath.

So normally you can remove this line :

```
config.setEngineHome( "C:/birt-runtime-3_7_0/ReportEngine" );
```

If you still have NullPointerException, check your permissions.

Hope that helps you.

**Edit :** i'm not having issue anymore, i was badly packaging my executable jar, now works like a charm ! So i can confirm that you don't need the above line with 3.7 and above.